# java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera.setParameters

Tags: java, android, camera

i know that the question was asked before, and i did read all the solutions, but my case is kinda strange, i keep getting on Crash report on developer account the following:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method:0)   at
>   android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:2080)   at
>   com.xxxxxxxxxx.core.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.surfaceCreated(BackgroundVideoRecorder.java:119)
>   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:675)   at
>   android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:185)   at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2050)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1117)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6175)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773) 
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)

Removed the application name for the sake of advertising, i tried the application on multiple devices and i cannot arrive to reproduce the error, even tho the devices that i tried it are available in the crash report, and in my parameter generation process i made sure to check if every parameter is supported, by checking the camera params here the code bellow:

```
   if (front) {
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setRotation(90);
            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                Log.w("VideoTakerFront","Continuous Video Supported");
            }
        } else {
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setRotation(270);
            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                Log.w("VideoTakerBack","Continuous Video Supported");
            }
        }
        camera.setParameters(params);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
                    camera.enableShutterSound(false);
                }
                else{
                    AudioManager audio= (AudioManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0,   AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                }
        Log.w("VideoTaker", "Open Camera");
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you check which API those devices are running because `android.hardware.Camera` is deprecated on API 21 and above, maybe that cause the crash

Comment: so i need to use Camera API 2 for devices higher then 21 ? but i have a 7.0 device and i don't face the problem O.o

Comment: You are always highly recommended to replace deprecated code.

Comment: i cannot find proper tutorials to implement  Camera Api2 code :/

Comment: `setParameters()` is a fragile function. It can fail with **RuntimeException** for many reasons, and your code must be prepared to swallow these. Usually, if the parameters themselves are legitimate, retry will succeed.

Comment: so i just set a try catch with a toast to retry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem... The users that reported the issue was using an older version of the application, i did not pay attention for the version, this problem used to happen in an older version, before I didn't use to get supported focus mode and check if it is available, thank you!